# Building Static Routing Network

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-commands, packet-tracer

I cannot get a successful connection between the three PCs. These are the commands im using on the relevant routers. What am I doing wrong / missing here.

I know that the show ip route command is

IP route *network address, subnet-mask, (ip address (next hop) | exit interface)*

R2 :

 ip route 172.16.3.0 255.255.255.0 s0/0/0 
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 s0/0/1

R1: 
ip route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 s0/0/0

R3: 
ip route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 s0/0/1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you have entered the correct exit interfaces on the static routes you have configured. As such, you should be able to:

1. Ping from PC2 to PC1
2. Ping from PC2 to PC3

What you shouldn't be able to do is:

1. Ping from PC1 to PC3 and vice-versa

This is because you have static routes to the R1-Lan and R3-Lan on R2 but only have static routes to the R2-Lan on both R1 and R3.

When you ping from R1 to R3, you're actually able to send the packets till R3. When R3 recieves the packet and tries to reply, it checks it's routing table and has no route back to R1 and hence drops the packet.

Basically, you have to add a static route to R3-Lan from R1 and vice-versa.

So, you just need to add the following commands on R1 and R3:

On R1:
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 s/0/0/0

On R3:
ip route 172.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 s/0/0/1

This should resolve your issue.